# Ruby API wrapper module

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm writing a wrapper for a third party `REST` API using HTTParty.  I would like to be able to call the third party API using a call to my local module like this:

```
APIWrapper::APIObject::APIMethod
```

I would like to write a magic function inside APIWrapper that accepts the function call and decodes the Object and Method to make a call to the third party API.  So the call above would do something like this:

```
params = {
  'format' = 'json',
  'object' = api_object,
  'method' = api_method,
}

get(APIWrapper::BASE_URI, {:query => params})
```

I want to be able to populate `api_object` and `api_method` automatically based on the method called so I don't have to explicitly write a method for every API call I want to be able to make.  In `PHP`, this would be done using a magic __get method.  Is there an equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: Look up `method_missing`.

Comment: Should api_object be the name of the object as a string? Same with api_method?

Comment: Yes, APIObject will be the name of the object.  So it will be something like "User" or "Account".  And APIMethod will be something like "create", "update", or "getAll".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can definitely be done in Ruby. You need to implement `const_missing` on APIWrapper, which will return an object that implements `method_missing` to get the API method part:

```
module APIWrapper
  def const_missing(const_name)
    anon_class = Class.new do
      def method_missing(name, *params, &block)
        params = {
          'format' = 'json',
          'object' = const_name.to_s,
          'method' = name.to_s,
        }
        get(APIWrapper::BASE_URI, {:query => params})
      end
    end
  end
end
```